# Property of a normal topological space

Tags: general-topology

I'm having great difficulty in understanding John M. Lee's proof of Lemma 4.80 p. 112 in his book Topological Manifolds.

Given 
X Hausdorff && X normal && A closed in X && U a neighborhood of A

==> There exists another neighborhood of A (called V) such that the closure of V is contained in U.

His hint is to take B equal to X \ U.  B being the other closed set in the definition of normality on p. 111

I'd love to see a diagram showing A, U, X and V

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my poor drawing skills, but here's a diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEXZ3.jpg.

I used continuous lines for closed sets (the part inside the line), and broken lines for open sets (I assumed neighborhoods to be open by default, otherwise the diagram would get more messy but it's the same idea).

So $U$ is the open neighbourhood containing $A$ and $X - U$ is closed.

By normality, there is an open set $X - W$ containing $X-U$, and an open set $V$ containing $A$, which are disjoint.

Then $W$ is closed in $X$ and contains $V$, so the closure of $V$ is contained in $W$, which in turn is contained in $U$.